# Node.js separate module dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

What is the best way to separate all module dependencies into a new file called **`dependencies.js`**, and requiring that file in for example **`server.js`**. How do i return all these requires?

```
var express = require('express')
  , stylus = require('stylus')
  , fs = require('fs')
  , https = require('https')
  , app = express();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to assign them to the `global` object, so you **shouldn't do it at all**

```
global.express = require('express');
global.stylus = require('stylus');
global.fs = require('fs')
global.https = require('https')
global.app = global.express();
```

---

There are actually a lot of reasons not to do this, but I'll boil it down. First, you know that when declaring a variable in a module (e.g. `var Foo = require('foo')`), that variable is a part of the local scope of that module. `global` on the other hand is global to all of the modules. Think about the implications of *all* your modules sharing the same namespace for critical things which can not be guaranteed to be in any one state at a particular point in run-time (`global` is actually reset whenever node decides it needs to be!). This problem is potentially exacerbated if you ever begin using multiple processes (as @Hippo mentioned but did not explain).

I can see why this would **seem** like a good idea at first, but the tiny amount of DRY you'd get from this technique pales in comparison to the unexpected failures you'd be hiding in your code.

IMO, it's much better to explicitly declare your dependencies in each module anyway. Sharing a list of deps across all modules would obfuscate the logical structure of your program.

Comment: Ok. Whats the difference of assigning them to the global object, and just define them without the var statement and making them global variables?

Comment: The traditional 'global' namespace in a node module isn't truly global; it's a disposable namespace that's destroyed after the module is evaluated.

Comment: You will run into some serious problems if you start to use multiple processes. If some of these module use some native code you probably will get other undesired side effects.

Comment: @bkconrad I just wanted to make more clear that this not a good idea at all.